# Cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 5

Tags: windows, python-3.x, numpy

This is my python code. I have an excel file named test.csv with some data in it.

```
    import numpy as np
    import os
    f=open('test.csv')
    data=f.read()
    f.close()
    lines=data.split('\n')
    header=lines[0].split(',')
    lines=lines[1:]
    print(header)
    float_data=np.zeros((len(lines),len(header)-1))
    for i,line in enumerate (lines):
        values=[float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
        float_data[i,:]=values
```

This is my [excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DCWZ.jpg)

Everytime i run, i get this error "Cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array with dimension 5."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likely cause:

```
In [76]: y=np.zeros((3,5))
In [77]: y[0,:]=[]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-e62a2beed947> in <module>()
----> 1 y[0,:]=[]

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 0 to array axis with dimension 5
```

For some `line`, `values` is an empty list.  Maybe a blank line?

```
[float(x) for x in ''.split(',')[1:]]
```

Comment: That's all the data i attached in the picture. There is no empty line. Why am i getting this error.

Comment: Is it possible that the code is running even after the data has ended?  
Because when i change the line to  
    `lines=line[1:37]`
I get no error

Comment: look at `lines` in the python session.

Comment: Yeah the code was running on an empty line. Thanks.